# Native websocket in python

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

Is there a reason why there is no websocket lib, based on asyncio, in Python core?

It sounds relevant for me as websockets are now a standard, supported by all modern browsers and asyncio is in the good way to be the new standard to handle concurrency un Python.

Note: I do not try to solve any problem, this is only to enrich my general knowledge.

Comment: That's a question for the package's maintainers, not SO.

Comment: Ok, I rephrase.

Comment: Still not a question for SO. If you want to have a discussion about the future of the language or its libraries, you'll have to find somewhere else.

Comment: I rephrase again :)

Comment: Nope. That's one for the Python core maintainers. But there isn't an asyncio http library in the standard library, aiohttp is third party, so skipping that straight to ws seems unlikely.

Comment: What is the point of this question? Even if had a clear-cut answer, how would the answer help you solve a problem you are having?

Comment: I do not try to solve any problem, this is only to enrich my general knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) evolves much faster than Python itself: we make several aiohttp releases per year while Python is released every year and half.

That's why aiohttp will never be a part of Python standard library.

Note, the same situation is for [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and other HTTP frameworks like Django.